# Cloud Functions for Firebase Storage Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions for Firebase and have had success uploading files to storage. But today I am getting this error

> Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket.

Does this have something to do with my storage rules I have set up?

Comment: Unless you can share the minimal code/configuration that is needed to reproduce the problem, there is not a lot anyone can do here on Stack Overflow. In that case, I'd recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the ACLs for your buckets aren't set up properly. We're working on ways to automagically fix them if we notice they're wrong, but it may take a little to roll that out.

In the mean time, install the latest Cloud SDK: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/ 
and run these in your favorite terminal:

```
gsutil defacl ch -p viewers-<PROJECT-ID>:R gs://<BUCKET-ID>
gsutil defacl ch -p editors-<PROJECT-ID>:O gs://<BUCKET-ID>
gsutil defacl ch -p owners-<PROJECT-ID>:O gs://<BUCKET-ID>
gsutil -m acl -r ch -p owners-<PROJECT-ID>:O gs://<BUCKET-ID>
gsutil -m acl -r ch -p viewers-<PROJECT-ID>:R gs://<BUCKET-ID>
gsutil -m acl -r ch -p editors-<PROJECT-ID>:O gs://<BUCKET-ID>
```

It's likely you'll only need to run the top three to set the default ACLs, rather than the per object ACLs (as per the bottom three).